# Add an event to a Stateless Component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

Is there any possible way to attach an `Event` to a stateless `Component`? Let me explain my question below:

I have a stateless component for `bootstrap` button as:

```
export const Button = props => {
  return (
    <button
      className={`btn btn-${props.type} ${props.class}`}
      type={props.buttonType}
    >
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

And I'm using the `<Button/>` component in `Parent` Component called `Container` as:

```
class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  sendData() {
    // method logic
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button type="primary" class="">
        Save Changes
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

To call `sendData()` method by clicking on `Button` component I have tried:

```
<Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.sendDate()}>
  Save Changes
</Button>
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there any possible way to attach an event to a stateless `Component` to call a `Method` from `Parent` Component.

I search over the Google but was unable to find the solution to this question, so please help me if you have any solution. Thanks much :)

Comment: Since `Button` (capital B) is a component, `onClick` here is passed as a prop and doesn't register an event listener. As such, you can in `button` (lowercase b) do: `<button onClick={props.onClick} />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to pass your event handler to your `Button` component and add `onClick` to default html `button` component

Try the following:

```
export const Button = (props) => {
    return(
        <button 
            onClick={props.onClick}
            className={`btn btn-${props.type} ${props.class}`} 
            type={props.buttonType}>
            {props.children}
        </button>
    )
}
```

---

```
class Container extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  }
    }

    sendData(e) {
        // logic here
    }

    render() { 
        return ( <Button onClick={(e) => this.sendData(e) } type='primary' class=''>Save Changes</Button> )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you meant is to call a function from the parent component from the child component?

So:

```
export const Button = (props) => {
  const buttonOnClick = this.props.buttonOnClick;

  return (
    <button 
      className={`btn btn-${props.type} ${props.class}`} 
      type={props.buttonType}
      {props.children}
      onClick={buttonOnClick(e)} // Onclick handled here calling the parent function via props.
    >
    </button>
  )
}



class Container extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { }
    }

    sendData(event) {
        // method logic
    }

    render() { 
        return ( <Button type='primary' class='' buttonOnClick={(e) => this.sendData(e)}>Save Changes</Button> )
    }
}
```

Basically, the sendData function is passed down from the parent function to the child as props and called via onClick.

Answer (score 1):

```
export const Button = (props) => {
return(
    <button 
        className={`btn btn-${props.type} ${props.class}`} 
        type={props.buttonType}
        onClick={props.onClick}
        >
        {props.children}
    </button>
  )
}
```